# Get filenames from directory where filename like

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I need to get the filenames of files in a directory where the filename is like a passed in string(Partnumber in my example) and put them in an array.

For example, if my passed in value = 1234_ I want to search the directory and put into the array files such as: 1234.jpg, 1234_1.jpg, 1234_2.jpg and so on.

My first attempt is my code below, which does not work for what I need to accomplish. What do I need to do here?

```
String Path = Server.MapPath("~/PartImages/" + Partnumber + "_" );

String[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_

Comment: Change the last part of your `Path` to `"*.jpg"` instead of `"_"`.

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation before asking a question, not only is there several methods that do this with another parameter, its clearly stated in the method documentation that * is a wild card

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. The wild card did the trick.